# Injecting derived test class via dependency injection uses base class function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a library that looks like this:

```
class BaseType {
    public string MyFunction() {
        return "Abc";
    }
}

class MyClass {
    public MyClass(BaseType baseType) {
        Console.WriteLine(myType.MyFunction());
    }
}
```

Now I am testing it like this:

```
class TestingBaseType : BaseType {
    public new string MyFunction() {
        return "def";
    }
}

class Unittests {
    public void Test() {
        new MyClass(new TestingBaseType());
        //Logs "Abc". But I need "def".
    }
}
```

My real code is not executing the injected mock `BaseClass`. How do I test like this without editing the production code. I don't want to edit production code because of the way I write a unit test.

Comment: The behavior is correct. Do not confuse `new` for `virtual` + `override`.

Comment: I understand that this behavior is correct, but I don't want to make `BaseType.MyFunction` virtual because I don't think unittests should affect your productiion code. People will wonder why a method is virtual.

Comment: The use an interface and two separate implementation. If you aspire for dependency injection, interfaces are the way to go anyway.

Comment: I completely agree with @OndrejTucny. Prefer Composition over Inheritance and use interfaces instead of base classes when it comes to modelling abstractions that contain the application's behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't make the base class's method virtual, then don't use a derived class and declare an interface instead. Interfaces are the key concept to enable effective dependency injection anyway.

Production code:

```
public interface IType
{
    string MyFunction();
}

public class MyType : IType
{
    public string MyFunction() => "Abc";
}

class MyClass 
{
    public MyClass(IType myType) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myType.MyFunction());
    }
}
```

Testing code:

```
public class MyTestingType : IType
{
    public string MyFunction() => "Def";
}

class Unittests 
{
    public void Test() 
    {
        new MyClass(new MyTestingType());
    }
}
```